# Difficulty in following Tizen Native Webview tutorial

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm following this [tutorial](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/native/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.native.appprogramming/html/tutorials/web_tutorial/webview_tutorial.htm) from the Tizen developers website.

I cannot understand where exactly to put the code snippets being discussed. From how the tutorial was presented they don't really tell you which code goes where. Been at it for days now.

How should the final .c file look like exactly?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code that will help you to understand a Complete Native Webview example:

```
    #include "webviewexample.h"

    // Header files needed for  EWK Webkit
    #include "EWebKit.h"

    typedef struct appdata {
        Evas_Object *win;
        Evas_Object *conform;
        Evas_Object *label;
        Evas_Object *entry;
        Evas_Object *web_view;
        Evas_Object *back_button;
        Evas_Object *forward_button;
    } appdata_s;

    static void
    win_back_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
    {
        appdata_s *ad = data;
        /* Let window go to hide state. */
        elm_win_iconified_set(ad->win, EINA_TRUE);
    }

    static void
    btn_go_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
    {
        appdata_s* ad = data;
        ewk_view_url_set(ad->web_view, elm_object_text_get(ad->entry) );
    }

    static void
    btn_prev_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
    {
        appdata_s* ad = data;
        if( ewk_view_back_possible( ad->web_view ) == EINA_TRUE )
            ewk_view_back( ad->web_view );
    }

    static void
    btn_next_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
    {
        appdata_s* ad = data;
        if( ewk_view_forward_possible( ad->web_view ) == EINA_TRUE )
            ewk_view_forward( ad->web_view );
    }

    static void
    view_focus_set(appdata_s *ad, Eina_Bool focus)
    {
       // We steal focus away from elm focus model and start to do things
       // manually here, so elm now has no clue what is up. Tell elm that its
       // top level UI component is to be unfocused so elm gives up the focus
       elm_object_focus_set(elm_object_top_widget_get(ad->win), EINA_FALSE);
       evas_object_focus_set(ad->web_view, focus);
    };

    static void
    on_mouse_down(void *data, Evas *e, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
    {
        appdata_s* ad = data;
        Evas_Event_Mouse_Down *ev= (Evas_Event_Mouse_Down *)event_info;

        if(ev->button == 1)
            view_focus_set(ad, EINA_TRUE);
    }

    static void
    my_table_pack(Evas_Object *table, Evas_Object *child, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
       evas_object_size_hint_align_set(child, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
       evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(child, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
       elm_table_pack(table, child, x, y, w, h);
       evas_object_show(child);
    }

    static void
    create_base_gui(appdata_s *ad)
    {
        /* set up policy to exit when last window is closed */
        elm_policy_set(ELM_POLICY_QUIT, ELM_POLICY_QUIT_LAST_WINDOW_CLOSED);
        /* Window */
        ad->win = elm_win_util_standard_add(PACKAGE, PACKAGE);
        elm_win_autodel_set(ad->win, EINA_TRUE);

        int rots[4] = { 0, 90, 180, 270 };
        elm_win_wm_rotation_available_rotations_set(ad->win, (const int *)(&rots), 4);

        eext_object_event_callback_add(ad->win, EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK, win_back_cb, ad);

        /* Conformant */
        /*ad->conform = elm_conformant_add(ad->win);
        elm_win_indicator_mode_set(ad->win, ELM_WIN_INDICATOR_SHOW);
        elm_win_indicator_opacity_set(ad->win, ELM_WIN_INDICATOR_OPAQUE);
        evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(ad->conform, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
        elm_win_resize_object_add(ad->win, ad->conform);
        evas_object_show(ad->conform);*/

        /* Label*/
        /*ad->label = elm_label_add(ad->conform);
        elm_object_text_set(ad->label, "Hello EFL");
        evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(ad->label, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
        elm_object_content_set(ad->conform, ad->label);
        evas_object_show(ad->label);*/

        {
            /* Box to put the table in so we can bottom-align the table
             * window will stretch all resize object content to win size */
            Evas_Object *box = elm_box_add(ad->win);
            evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(box, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
            elm_win_resize_object_add(ad->win, box);
            evas_object_show(box);

            /* Table */
            Evas_Object *table = elm_table_add(ad->win);
            /* Make table homogenous - every cell will be the same size */
            elm_table_homogeneous_set(table, EINA_TRUE);
            /* Set padding of 10 pixels multiplied by scale factor of UI */
            elm_table_padding_set(table, 5 * elm_config_scale_get(), 10 * elm_config_scale_get());
            /* Let the table child allocation area expand within in the box */
            evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(table, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
            /* Set table to fiill width but align to bottom of box */
            evas_object_size_hint_align_set(table, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
            elm_box_pack_end(box, table);
            evas_object_show(table);

            {
                /* Entry */
                ad->entry = elm_entry_add(ad->win);
                elm_entry_scrollable_set(ad->entry, EINA_TRUE);
                eext_entry_selection_back_event_allow_set(ad->entry, EINA_TRUE);
                elm_object_text_set(ad->entry, "http://www.tizen.org");
                my_table_pack(table, ad->entry, 0, 0, 3, 1);

                /* Button-1 */
                Evas_Object *btn = elm_button_add(ad->win);
                elm_object_text_set(btn, "Prev");
                evas_object_smart_callback_add(btn, "clicked", btn_prev_cb, ad);
                my_table_pack(table, btn, 0, 1, 1, 1);

                /* Button-2 */
                btn = elm_button_add(ad->win);
                elm_object_text_set(btn, "Go");
                evas_object_smart_callback_add(btn, "clicked", btn_go_cb, ad);
                my_table_pack(table, btn, 1, 1, 1, 1);

                /* Button-3 */
                btn = elm_button_add(ad->win);
                elm_object_text_set(btn, "Next");
                evas_object_smart_callback_add(btn, "clicked", btn_next_cb, ad);
                my_table_pack(table, btn, 2, 1, 1, 1);

                /* WebView */
                Evas *evas = evas_object_evas_get(ad->win);
                ad->web_view = ewk_view_add(evas);
                ewk_view_url_set(ad->web_view, elm_object_text_get(ad->entry) );

                //Handling Mouse Event
                evas_object_event_callback_add(ad->web_view, EVAS_CALLBACK_MOUSE_DOWN, on_mouse_down, ad);

                my_table_pack(table, ad->web_view, 0, 2, 3, 8);


            }
        }

        /* Show window after base gui is set up */
        evas_object_show(ad->win);
    }

    static bool
    app_create(void *data)
    {
        /* Hook to take necessary actions before main event loop starts
            Initialize UI resources and application's data
            If this function returns true, the main loop of application starts
            If this function returns false, the application is terminated */
        appdata_s *ad = data;

        create_base_gui(ad);

        return true;
    }

    static void
    app_control(app_control_h app_control, void *data)
    {
        /* Handle the launch request. */
    }

    static void
    app_pause(void *data)
    {
        /* Take necessary actions when application becomes invisible. */
    }

    static void
    app_resume(void *data)
    {
        /* Take necessary actions when application becomes visible. */
    }

    static void
    app_terminate(void *data)
    {
        /* Release all resources. */
    }

    static void
    ui_app_lang_changed(app_event_info_h event_info, void *user_data)
    {
        /*APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED*/
        char *locale = NULL;
        system_settings_get_value_string(SYSTEM_SETTINGS_KEY_LOCALE_LANGUAGE, &locale);
        elm_language_set(locale);
        free(locale);
        return;
    }

    int
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        appdata_s ad = {0,};
        memset(&ad, 0x00, sizeof(appdata_s));
        int ret = 0;

        ui_app_lifecycle_callback_s event_callback = {0,};
        memset(&event_callback, 0x00, sizeof(ui_app_lifecycle_callback_s));
        app_event_handler_h handlers[5] = {NULL, };

        event_callback.create = app_create;
        event_callback.terminate = app_terminate;
        event_callback.pause = app_pause;
        event_callback.resume = app_resume;
        event_callback.app_control = app_control;

        ui_app_add_event_handler(&handlers[APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED], APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED, ui_app_lang_changed, &ad);

        ret = ui_app_main(argc, argv, &event_callback, &ad);
        if (ret != APP_ERROR_NONE) {
            dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "app_main() is failed. err = %d", ret);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the link for your understanding:
[Tizen Mobile 2.3 WebViewer Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388759/tizen-mobile-2-3-webviewer-example)

I Hope that might help you.